# Removing a single character globally from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on the following demo. Why am I not able to properly remove all `[` from the string?

I tried `tr.replace(/[/g, "")` and `tr.replace(/'['/g, "")` and even `tr.replace(//[/g, "")` but none of them working

```js
let str = "Mr [ has a [ house and a [ car";
console.log(str.replace(/[/g, ""));
console.log(str.replace(//[/g, ""));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just escape it with a slash `\` because `]` has special meaning on regex. Also replace multiple white-space with a single white-splace with another `replace()` operation.

```js
let str = "Mr [ has a [ house and a [ car";
console.log(str.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/  +/g, ' '));
```